# Django "dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required"

Tags: python, django, dictionary

I am trying to make multi-page registration form to work, and I think that I am close to making it work, but I keep getting errors. I am using built-in user model and extending it with one-to-one relationship.

This is models.py file:

```
class Dadilja(models.Model):
    korisnik = models.OneToOneField(User)
    ime = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    prezime = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    datum_rođenja = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    mjesto = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    mjesto_obavljanja = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    broj_telefona = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    slika_profila = models.ImageField(upload_to="slika_profila", blank=True)
    iskustvo = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    dostupna = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    about = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    broj_djece = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    dodatno = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    cijena = models.PositiveIntegerField()
```

forms.py:

```
class Forma1(forms.ModelForm):
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())
        class Meta():
            model = User
            fields = ("username", "email", "password")


class Forma2(forms.ModelForm):
    datum_rođenja = forms.DateField(widget=forms.SelectDateWidget(years=reversed(range(1930,2000))))
    class Meta():
        model = Dadilja
        fields = ("ime", "prezime", "datum_rođenja", "mjesto", "mjesto_obavljanja", "broj_telefona")

class Forma3(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta():
        model = Dadilja
        fields = ("slika_profila", "iskustvo", "dostupna", "about", "broj_djece", "dodatno", "cijena")
```

and most importantly, views.py file:

```
def dadilja_registracija_3(request):
    dadilja2 = Forma3(data=request.POST)
    if request.method == "POST" and dadilja2.is_valid():
        print(dadilja2.cleaned_data)
        korisnik = request.session['form_data_page_1']
        dadilja1 = request.session['form_data_page_2']
        user = User(username=korisnik['username'], email=korisnik['email'], password=korisnik['password'])
       user.set_password(user.password)
       user.save()
```

> ```
>         privremeno = {}
>         for dadilja in dadilja2.cleaned_data:
>             privremeno.update(dadilja)
> ```

```
        dadilja1 = Dadilja(korisnik=user, ime=dadilja1['ime'],
            prezime=dadilja1['prezime'],
            datum_rođenja=dadilja1['datum_rođenja'],
            mjesto=dadilja1['mjesto'],
            mjesto_obavljanja=dadilja1['mjesto_obavljanja'],
            slika_profila=privremeno['slika_profila'],
            iskustvo=privremeno['iskustvo'],
            about=privremeno['about'],
            broj_djece=privremeno['broj_djece'],
            dodatno=privremeno['dodatno'],
            cijena=privremeno['cijena'])

        if 'slika_profila' in request.FILES:
            dadilja.slika_profila = request.FILES['slika_profila']

        dadilja1.save()

    else:
        dadilja2 = Forma3()
    return render(request, 'accounts/dadilja3.html', {'dadilja2' : dadilja2})
```

I keep getting Value error: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required. The problem is in view called "dadilja_registracija_3" in dictionary "privremeno" that I higlited.

This is making me crazy, I don't know what to do anymore. Tnx in advance

Comment: What are the steps that lead to this error (which view/form is called). Post the stack trace - and point out which lines in your code are indicated in the stack trace.

Comment: I edited the original post.  The problem is in view called "dadilja_registracija_3" in dictionary "privremeno" that I higlited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does not work, as you have noticed:

```
privremeno = {}
for dadilja in dadilja2.cleaned_data:
    privremeno.update(dadilja)
```

You can either just add all of `cleaned_data` like this:

```
privremeno = copy(dadilja2.cleaned_data)
```

or

```
privremeno = {}
privremeno.update(dadilja2.cleaned_data)
```

or

```
privremeno = {}
for key,value in dadilja2.cleaned_data:
    privremeno[key] = value
```

or

```
privremeno = {key:value for key,value in dadilja2.cleaned_data}
```

EDIT: It's worth having a look at the generic form views of Django. They will do all this for you and you can concentrate on creating the markup in your template using the form data that is added by Django automatically: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/

Answer (score 0):

Update your dict like this

```
privremeno = {}
for k, v in dadilja2.cleaned_data.items():
    privremeno.update({k:v})
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass dictionary to `update()`

```
privremeno.update({dadilja: dadilja2.cleaned_data[dadilja]})
```